# Cannot download stagehand for dart

Tags: dart, vpn, http-status-code-403

Ive been trying to download for the entire day the stagehand to be able to use dart in vs code and I keep getting this error. Already tried with VPN but still doesn't work. Please I need help need it to work.

```
PS C:\>  pub global activate stagehand
 Resolving dependencies...
 + args 1.6.0 
 + charcode 1.1.3
 + collection 1.14.13
 + http 0.12.2
 + http_parser 3.1.4
 + meta 1.2.4
 + path 1.7.0
 + pedantic 1.9.2
 + source_span 1.7.0
 + stagehand 3.3.11
 + string_scanner 1.0.5
 + term_glyph 1.1.0
 + typed_data 1.2.0
 + usage 3.4.2
 Downloading stagehand 3.3.11...
 HTTP error 403: Forbidden
 package:pub/src/http.dart 221:5                 _ThrowingClient.send
 ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
 package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart 33:31  ThrottleClient.send
 ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
 package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 399:37       BoundHostedSource._download
 ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
 package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 266:13       BoundHostedSource.downloadToSystemCache
 package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 201:50     GlobalPackages._installInCache.<fn>.<fn>
 package:pub/src/http.dart 278:51                withDependencyType
 package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 197:14     GlobalPackages._installInCache.<fn>
 dart:async                                      Future.wait
 package:pub/src/global_packages.dart 196:18     GlobalPackages._installInCache
 dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
 package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart      VersionSolver.solve
 dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
 package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart              BoundHostedSource.withPrefetching
 dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
 package:pub/src/rate_limited_scheduler.dart     RateLimitedScheduler.withPrescheduling
 dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
 package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart              BoundHostedSource.withPrefetching.<fn>
 dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
 package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart      VersionSolver.solve.<fn>  
 dart:async                                      _completeOnAsyncReturn
 package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart      VersionSolver._result
 This is an unexpected error. Please run

 pub --trace global activate stagehand
```

Comment: and did you try what error suggests?  `pub --trace global activate stagehand`

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem. And yes tried the pub-- trace global, also didn't worked. The package downloaded successfully after installing the flutter SDK and android studio. Apparently stagehand runs through flutter asumin you already have it. If you don't gives a 403 forbidden.